# SQL Repeated entries by time

Tags: mysql, repeat

I have a database which is tracking the date a transaction takes place, in addition to the unique buyer that transaction corresponds to - now I am trying to look at reservations which resulted in a customer purchasing again at a later date. Right now, the code and sample output below shows me which customers were repeat customers by the count of their buyer_id, but I also want to be able to to see which purchases (reservations) resulted in that same customer purchasing again at a later time (not earlier in time, which could be the case by using a simple "Count").

```
SELECT r.id AS Reservation_id, r.created, r.buyer_id, COUNT(r.buyer_id)
FROM reservations r
GROUP BY r.buyer_id
ORDER BY Reservation_id


 Reservation_id   created             buyer_id     COUNT(r.buyer_id)
 3                2007-08-14 18:28:38   438           1
 7                2007-09-19 12:29:52   474           2
 8                2007-09-19 13:14:54   476           1
 9                2007-09-20 10:22:52   477           1
 10               2007-09-25 15:27:45   485           3
 11               2007-09-26 20:56:25   474           2
 12 .... etc
```

The goal is to be able to pull additional data about each reservation and then see what factors of service have an effect on a customer coming back for a repeat purchase. In the case above, buyer #474 purchased twice, but I want to be able to distinguish the first purchase (when he/she did indeed come back a purchase again, the 2nd and final purchase) from the second purchase (after which no other purchases were made by buyer #474). In this case, the goal is to have another output row that shows:

```
Reservation_id   created             buyer_id    COUNT(r.buyer_id) Returning
 3                2007-08-14 18:28:38   438           1              0
 7                2007-09-19 12:29:52   474           2              1
 8                2007-09-19 13:14:54   476           1              0
 9                2007-09-20 10:22:52   477           1              0
 10               2007-09-25 15:27:45   485           3              1
 11               2007-09-26 20:56:25   474           2              0
 12 .... etc
```

i.e., showing how customer 474's ID does not show up again after reservations_id 11. I would do this in excel but I have a huge amount of rows and excel can't handle the functions over such a large dataset.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

What you are trying to do is called recurrent event analysis.  In particular, it is part of a branch of statistics/data mining called "survival analysis".

Your approach (which is perfectly possible in SQL) leads to biased results and biased conclusions, for the simple reason that someone whose first purchase was long ago has a much greater chance of returning than someone whose first purchase was yesterday.

My response to questions is almost never to read one of my books.  However, the book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel" has two chapters on survival analysis.  These can help you understand such time-to-event problems, from a practical perspective.